# Java- Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I was given a maven project for eclipse. It had access to no longer existing repos and used jar files from those repos. Those jar files are public so I can get them if needed. Maven would grab the jar file and be able to compile anything that refrenced that jar file. My question is how do get that public jar file onto my local system if the repo is gone and maven still requires it as a dependency. All dependencies are of the provided scope.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the pom.xml file and point to other maven repositories which are still available. Unless you are looking for a very particular jar file, there are a lot of maven repositories available for public access.

This is how you do it: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories
Repositories to look for:

1. http://mvnrepository.com
2. Maven central
3. JBoss Maven Repository etc.